# Computer Freezes Locks screen since I installed Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I upgraded my two computers to Windows 10 recently. One is working fine. The other will freeze occasionally after it sits idle for a few hours. This seems to be random. Some days it is fine. Other days it will freeze several times a day. We have to reboot it and then it is OK again; but this is very annoying.

I have tried the suggestions I found googling the problem but to no avail.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggestion elsewhere on this site which was to create Custom power plan. The Customer power plan can be the same as your current power plan.

Since that time I have only had one freeze. It hasn't frozen in several days.

So I am assuming that this fixed the problem.

I am editing this to say that the suggestion did not solve my problem after all. So I am still looking for suggestions.